# Node information in a PostGIS dataset

Tags: postgis, qgis-3, topology, network

I am working in QGIS / PostGIS to plan the cable layout for a seismic array. The power distribution is from the green point with the white cross in the middle. The nine green points marked with a voltage are the seismic sites. The entire area is about 1x1 km2

[image]

For practical reasons, we need to use 48V power supply out to the sites, so to avoid a too large power drop, we need cables with a bigger area. For practical reasons, we are only using one type of cables, doubling, tripling or even quadrupling it up when needed. The network shown is one of many possible versions I have made. We want to try to do the most cost efficient cabling, that is least possible amount of cabling, as short trenches as possible and trying to have the trences in the right areas, following some dirt roads as much as possible at the same time having a high enough voltage at the sites. Those parts are (relatively) simple standard GIS works. And I can make an automatic report based on a planned layout.

On the map, the number of cables is symbolized by the number of lines, each distance is only digitized once, with an attribute telling how many cables there are at a give line. One further thing I would like to report on is where the number of cables are changing through a node, since that means that we would need to have an extra installation at that point. For this case, both ends of cable 48 (mid, left) would need an extra installation. At the right side there are two cables coming in from the bottom and two plus one going out, on the right side, there is one cable coming in from the right and two going out. There is always one direction coming in and usually one or two, but there could be more going out, so the logic would be, does the biggest number equal the sum of the smaller numbers. I have tried to always snap lines onto a node when making a meeting point, so my question is:

Is there somehow I can identify the nodes where lines are connected and identify those lines to do some maths on the attributes? This can be done either in QGIS or in PostGIS.

The lines are not directional as the direction may be different for a given cable for different configurations.

(If somebody wonders why there are many end nodes just connecting two lines, as this is one of many potential configurations, there may be multiway connections at those nodes in other configs, or there may be changes in other attributes, e.g. going from dirt road to terrain)

Comment: Could you please clarify this: *"identify the end nodes having more than one line connected to it"* Do you mean nodes which only have inbound lines, and no outbound ones? Which would these be on your screenshot (apart from most of the green sites)? Also, are your lines properly directional, that is, is the 1st vertex always on the node whence they are outbound, and the last on where they are inbound?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the ask here fully but im theory could you draw a small buffer around the end nodes and count the intersecting lines? If you want to determine groups of direction, you could potentially make use of the hausdorff distance.

Comment: It doesn't look like this is a repetitive analysis. I would do this in QGIS.

Comment: In postgis, you could join the point and line tables using st_dwithin(linegeom,pointgeom,tolerance).  You could then analyze the spatial and data relationships between the point and line(s) - distance, azimuth, number of connections, etc.

Comment: @crafter6029, I hope it is clearer now. I want to identify points when two or more lines meet. For directionallity, it could be useful, but as the current directions may change for different configurations, it is not useful in this case.

Comment: @BJW, this will be repeated until we have decided on a final configuration, also personally I often find one off SQL queries in postGIS simpler than an analysis in QGIS ;-)

Comment: responses would be more forthcoming if you included a data table structure

Comment: @jbalk, I do not have the points I want to work on as a separate dataset, I was hoping the nodes/vertexes at the end of the lines somehow would be availiable as a data set.

Comment: If the lines are LINESTRING type, you can use `st_startpoint(geom)` and `st_endpoint(geom)`.  For both LINESTRING and MULTILINESTRING, you can use `(st_dump(st_boundary(geom))).geom` to get all the start/end points, but you won't be able to differentiate between start/end.

Answer (score 0):

I had a hope I had overlooked some simple way of working on the vertexes at the ends of the lines, but it seems like that is not possible, so thanks to the tip from Timothy Dalton, I ended up doing it this way:

- running v.net to get the end points of lines
- Doing a small buffer around the points from v.net
- Doing an intersection between the buffer and the initial line cover
- Using aggregate to calculate summaries from the line cover from the intersection and make those as attributes on the pointcover from v.net.

The summaries were the number of cables connected to each point, the largest number of cables beeing connected to each point and the total number of connections to each point. Javing the total number of cables and the largest number of cables connected to a point, I could check if total != max *2, in which cases some work is to be done there.

So that answers my question.

In addition, using the total number of connections I could get rid of the end nodes that were of no interest (n=1).

It can also be done in postgis:

```
 with
  lines as
   (select line,n,id from hnet.kabelalternativer where versjon = 19),
  nodes as
   (select distinct st_intersection(ka1.line, ka2.line) as node
    from lines ka1, lines ka2
    where ka1.id > ka2.id and st_intersects(ka1.line,ka2.line)),
  buffer as
   (select st_buffer(nodes.node,1) as buffer, node from nodes),
  intersection as
   (select ka.n, buffer.node
    from buffer, lines ka 
    where st_intersects(buffer.buffer,ka.line))
select node, max(n), sum(n), sum(n)-max(n)*2 as diff from intersection group by node having sum(n)-max(n)*2 != 0
```

For either, I also did some other overlays with a layer on where the site are to be installed, as changes in the number of cables through a site is expected.

Rewriting the postgis query slightly, so the versjon is carried through, I could make a view that can give me an updated layer whenever I add a new version or review an old one.